# Does the registry location of IE proxy settings vary between versions of IE and Windows?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry, version

Under Windows XP, using Internet Explorer 6, the location of the proxy server is stored in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Does this differ with Internet Explorer 7/8/9 or Windows Vista/7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961) of Microsoft confirms that the registry path you gave,

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
```

is valid for IE6, IE7 and IE8. It makes no difference being on Windows XP, Vista or 7.